# Image getting rotated automatically on upload

Tags: php, rotation, gd, base64

I'm trying to upload a base64 encoded image and save after decoding it. Image is getting uploaded and saved, and I can access it using a URL and everything..but the image gets rotated by 90 degrees anti-clockwise and I have no idea WHY!!

The place where I get the encoded data is fine, as putting it in `<img />` works fine!

```
function saveImageData($base64Data) {
    $base64_decoded = base64_decode($base64Data);
    $im = imagecreatefromstring($base64_decoded);
    if ($im !== false) {
        $imagepath = '/public/uploads/' . time() . '.jpg';
        imagejpeg($im, $imagepath);
        chmod($imagepath, 0755);
        imagedestroy($im);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return $imagepath;
}
```

I'm not using any rotation functions, but still its getting rotated. I can use a PHP GD function like imagerotate, but don't want to for reasons like black backgrounds etc.

If you can help..you r the awesomest person!!

Comment: I know this is old, but just thought I'd mention: if you can help it, don't base64encode photos before uploading. You add something like 20% in size to it. PhoneGap supports file uploads http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

Comment: At the time, I was writing this, Phonegap was not Codorva, just Nitobi's Phonegap and the API didn't support multipart POST requests.
Also, we decided to dump Phonegap & go native!

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a mobile web app. Any Ideas why?

Answer (score 17):

My guess would be that the image you're uploading is actually rotated, but is being corrected because it contains rotation data in its EXIF section. (For example, a camera may be aware of portrait orientation when taking a photo, and save that information in the EXIF data; some viewing software is aware of the rotation data and will auto-rotate the photo when viewing it.) In which case, the image might just be *appearing* to be rotated for you, depending on what you're using to view it.

Are you viewing the "before upload" and "after upload" images using the same software? What happens if you look at them both using the same web browser, say?

What happens if you try a different image, preferably from a different source? Do you have any software that will allow you to view the image's EXIF data? Look for the "Orientation" value; anything other than "1" means there's a rotation set for the image (see [this page](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html) for a decent description.)

So, in summary, I'd say that that the underlying image in the JPEG file is at the "wrong" orientation, and the EXIF data contains information to correct that rotation for display. This is very likely if the source is, for example, an iPhone, which having just played with mine, seems to store its underlying image data in landscape orientation, but set the EXIF data if the image was actually taken (and should therefore be displayed) as portrait.

Best way to fix it is almost certainly to examine the EXIF data on the file after upload, using the [PHP EXIF functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) and rotate the image as necessary to correct the orientation before saving your own copy.

Comment: Thanx for your insight! I'm actually shooting a picture from the iPhone/iPod Touch camera or selecting from the iOS photo album. Basically, I'm building an iOS app using Phonegap (http://phonegap.com)
I'll check about this EXIF orientation stuff and get back..maybe this could be it!

Comment: Here's the Phonegap documentation (http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#Camera), that I'm following to get base64 encoded image data

Comment: @detj Yeah, if it's an image from an iPhone, I think my theory is likely to be right. For example, I just took two photos with my iPhone, one in landscape, one in portrait. Although they both appear to have the "correct" orientation in iPhoto, for example, the pictures themselves are *both* 2048 *wide* by 1536 *high*, even the "portrait" photo. The portrait photo is actually stored as landscape and the EXIF data says that it's rotated, so iPhoto auto-corrects. I guess the photo is making it through _unchanged_ to your website, but on display just the raw, unrotated image is shown.

Comment: @detj Incidentally, are you on a Mac, or something else? If on a Mac, you can get a real idea of what's going on with the [Simple EXIF Viewer](http://homepage.mac.com/aozer/EV/); I'm sure there's a Windows or Linux equivalent.

Comment: I am having the same issue when uploading from my Samsung S4 using cordova to a spring server

Comment: @DonovanThomson Yes, it's a common issue with mobile devices, because it takes a lot of memory/processing to rotate all the data in a large image. So, mobile devices, which are often limited in memory and CPU often do the trick of storing the image data in the camera's natural orientation, and setting orientation data so it can be displayed the correct way up when viewed.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $filePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $exif = exif_read_data($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($exif);
    echo "</pre>";
    if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
        $imageResource = imagecreatefromjpeg($filePath);
        switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
            case 3:
                $image = imagerotate($imageResource, 180, 0);
                break;
            case 6:
                $image = imagerotate($imageResource, -90, 0);
                break;
            case 8:
                $image = imagerotate($imageResource, 90, 0);
                break;
            default:
                $image = $imageResource;
        }
        imagejpeg($image, $filename, 90);
    }
}
?>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                        Choose img<input type="file" name="file" id="imgInp">
                    </span>
                </span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button name="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Super thank you very much ! Difficult to detect this error, on almost all support the Exif processed to display the photo on the correct way ! Amazing it's work perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue when making an mobile hybrid application that used Cordova to access an mobile phones camera and then post the image to the server. I resolved it by setting the correctOrientation property to true.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail,
                        {
                            quality: 80,
                            destinationType:Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                            correctOrientation : true
                        });
```