# Why some images uploaded in PHP are auto-rotated by 90 degrees?

Tags: php, image, upload, rotation

I am using PHP to upload files and images, some images I uploaded are auto rotated while I see it in image browser as normal image.

Comment: have you ever rotated those images in some tool because most of them doesn't rotate them physically rather they just keep info that this image will be displayed rotated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image getting rotated automatically on upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301006/image-getting-rotated-automatically-on-upload)

Answer (score 2):

Some images are rotated in the file.  Certain applications such as picassa, sometimes windows folders rotate the files for you based on information given about the camera etc.

Other applications such as web browsers do not, you can use various tools to rotate the images after uploading them or before (eg export them from picassa and it will rotate them automatically).  Search for php autorotate jpeg and you should turn up something.

Comment: talking about image rotation is an easy issue 
but the problem is about the image 
it seems not rotated in image browser 
and can't know if it will rotated after upload it 
is there a way from php to discover that before upload the image?

Comment: did you search like i suggested?

Comment: yes,, i'am using SimpleImage library and i found a function that may solve this problem >> auto_orient() >> it works fine in local but in server it didn't work .. i'am searching to solve this problem too

Comment: solved ,, after adding exif extension in php.ini file in server