# Image is getting rotated automatically by 90 degree in a web page

Tags: server, html

My code is just this:

```
<img src="uploads/619671548171334115-961656431.jpg" alt="a">
```

You can see this here yourself: 
https://moviesre.com/ogb/addtestimonial/testtt.php

This is the image: https://moviesre.com/ogb/addtestimonial/uploads/619671548171334115-961656431.jpg

See it is not flipped, but in the web page it is displaying flipped. What's up?

Edit: Not all images are getting roated on this server. Some images with smaller file size (in pixel not memory) are displaying normal

Comment: Why someone downvoted? This is a legit question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your uploaded image is rotated, but is being corrected because it contains rotation data in its EXIF ('Exchangeable Image File Format' is all the information that is automatically embedded into an image file when a photo is taken using a modern digital camera) section.

You can see EXIF data of your local file from [exifdata.com](http://exifdata.com) and also you can see EXIF data of your uploaded file (that server is providing to the browser) by using php function [exif_read_data()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php)

You can get full explanation [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5301280/6678086) of [@matt-gibson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300836/matt-gibson)

Comment: Yeah, it contain EXIF data. The image is already rotated, I just want to fix it. But I am getting that error. My code is correct, It is working for others, but not me. Any specific reason why? Is it server side problem? Any setting in php.ini file or something? I also tried it in XAMPP (default setting), and getting same error.